# jquery ajax not working without loading a page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

`

$previous_year = $year = 0;

$previous_month = $month = 0;

$ul_open = false;

$myposts = get_posts(array(

'numberposts' =>    $numposts,

'orderby'   =>    'post_date',

'order' => 'DESC'

));

foreach ($myposts as $post) : ?>

$year =    mysql2date('Y', $post->post_date);


$month = mysql2date('n', $post->post_date);


$day = mysql2date('j', $post->post_date);


?>

http://localhost/klientasnew/archives/?=01">

jQuery(document).ready( function(){     
  


jQuery('#df').on('click', function(e) { 


e.preventDefault();


var rml_post_id = jQuery(this).data( 'href' ); 


jQuery.ajax({


url : '/archives?=',


type : 'post',


data : {


post_id : rml_post_id


},


success : function( response ) {


//jQuery('#dd').html(response);


alert(response);


}


});
    


jQuery(this).hide();            


});     


});

`

Comment: add some text. explain what you trying to do and what was the error

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
$numposts       = -1;
$previous_year  = $year = 0;
$previous_month = $month = 0;
$ul_open        = false;

$myposts = get_posts(
    array(
        'numberposts' => $numposts,
        'orderby'     => 'post_date',
        'order'       => 'DESC',
    )
);

?>               

<?php foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : ?>

    <?php
    setup_postdata( $post );
    $year  = mysql2date( 'Y', $post->post_date );
    $month = mysql2date( 'n', $post->post_date );
    $day   = mysql2date( 'j', $post->post_date );
    ?>

    <?php if ( $year != $previous_year || $month != $previous_month ) : ?>

        <?php if ( $ul_open == true ) : ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<li><a id="df" rel="<?php echo get_the_date( 'm' ); ?>" href="
        <?php
            echo site_url();
        ?>
/archives?=<?php echo get_the_date( 'm' ); ?>" onclick="return loadmore();">

<span><?php the_time( 'F Y' ); ?></span></a>

</li>

        <?php $ul_open = true; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

    <?php
    $previous_year  = $year;
    $previous_month = $month;
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function loadmore(){ 

        e.preventDefault();

        var rml_post_id = jQuery(this).data( 'href' ); 

        jQuery.ajax({

            url : rml_post_id,
            type: 'post',
            data: {
            post_id: rml_post_id
            },
            success : function( response ) {
                //jQuery('#dd').html(response);
                alert(response);
                return false;
            }

        });
        jQuery(this).hide();            
    }  

    </script>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: its reloading into another page.i need to another page without reloading

Comment: i need to get a another page without reloading using jquery ajax

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $numposts = -1; <br>
```

$previous_year = $year = 0;

$previous_month = $month = 0;

$ul_open = false;

$myposts = get_posts(array(

'numberposts' => $numposts,

'orderby' => 'post_date',

'order' => 'DESC'

));?>

$year = mysql2date('Y', $post->post_date);

$month = mysql2date('n', $post->post_date);

$day = mysql2date('j', $post->post_date);?>

" >

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".get_project").click(function(){

        var id = $(this).attr("data_id");

        var data = '?='+ encodeURIComponent(id); // this where i add multiple data using  ' & '

        //alert(data);

        $.ajax({

            type:"GET",

            url: "/archives" + data, 

            success: function(html){

            $(".blg-bck").html(html);

        }

    });

      });

});